# What is this bug? (Northern Italy)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found two of these going around my room, looks like they entered from the window. Size is about 8-10 mm. Colour a very light translucent brown.

Any ideas of what it could be and if it's dangerous? The image is blurry as it was startled by the light and started running around :)

I live in Northern Italy and weather is humid heat (32° C, 62% RH) if that helps.

[image]

[image: image2]

Comment: That looks like a sow bug, but white. The ones in my area are brown.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Identifications questions should include: 1) one or more clear closeup photos of the organism (photos from multiple angles if possible); 2) the species-identification tag; and 3) habitat information. Please [edit] your post to include as much of this essential information as possible. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site.